# Django is applying background color , but not apllying background image from style.css

Tags: django, uwsgi, django-staticfiles

I run my django project with uwsgi.
It reads style.css file in statics/css .
There are two areas in style.css
It applies 1st area, but it does not apply 2nd area to the page.

and

```
1) #skin-blur-violate {
    background: #581528;
}
```

and

```
2) #skin-blur-violate {
    background-image: url(../img/body/violate.jpg);
}
```

Below is statics configuration in settings.

```
STATIC_URL = '/home/proj1/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/proj1/staticorj/static/',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your projects `urls.py`, add this code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static    



if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And In your `settings.py` only keep this code regarding **Static files** & exclude what you have earlier:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And, your **`static` folder tree** should be like this:

```
App
├── static
       ├── app
            └── images
            └── style.css
```

See if this works.

Comment: @ivbtar happy to help.